# python django - query returns blank result if searched agains mutiple column values for multiple rows and a few rows do not exist

Tags: django, database, list-comprehension, django-orm

I have a list namely `ids_found`that has a few values. These values are the primary keys in the database table `news`. If all the corresponding rows exist in the table, then I get the expected result i.e. `ids_found_result`. But  if any of them is missing, the result becomes just an empty list. The code follows here:

```
ids_found=[2,3,34]
ids_found_result=[]

clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(ids_found)])

ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses

ids_found_result = news.objects.filter(pk__in=ids_found).extra(
                                select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))

ids_found_result = list(ids_found_result)
```

How can I make it to produce the result when one or more rows are missing in the database ? If `n` number of rows are missing then the expected result should be the  `ids_found_result` containing elements less by `n`.

Comment: Do u mean u have an id in your `ids_found`, but that id does not exist in db?

Comment: yes, you go the thing

Comment: you *got the thing

Comment: 1) how long your ids_found can be? 2) ids there will always be sorted from lower to higher? Or they can be in random order?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, even with the same code (only swapping in a different model class). What if you run `news.objects.filter(pk__in=ids_found)` only, do you get results then even though you don't get results when you add the `.extra()` call?

Comment: @Chiefir, any order

Comment: @ryanmrubin, have to check